# How to add a volume bar like YouTube for iOS?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I am almost done with my game in Unity 5. However when the player presses Volume Up/Down, the iOS (version) shows the standard UI to show volume. Android has it's own (looks better on Stock).

I want to make my game consistent on either platform and different variations of Android. So I want to recreate how YouTube (for iOS) handles the change in volume.

I can't figure this out. Any help would be awesome!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity has no functionality to take over physical volume button, especially on iOS.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: So would I need to modify the iOS project and Android project separately to implement this feature? if so can there be a script to add it later?

Comment: Yes, considering both API on both systems are different, respectively.

Comment: I don't know exactly the script required for iOS and Android respectively, since I'm used to PC projects.

Comment: Can I use Unity to not display the Volume HUD